# SQL Splitting column data into multiple columns

Tags: sql, substring

This code is only giving us the first song for each album and we need all of them

```
insert into musicsongs
    select distinct
    [GROUP ID], [Album 1 ],SUBSTRING ([Songs 1],1, CHARINDEX (',', [Songs 1]) -1)
from dbo.Music_Import 
    where [Songs 1] is not null
    UNION
    select distinct
    [Group ID], [Album 2 ], SUBSTRING ([Songs 2],1, CHARINDEX (',', [Songs 2])-1) 
from dbo.Music_Import
    where [Songs 2] is not null
```

Comment: I think you do the opposite of which mentioned in the title.

Comment: Please tag your question with the brand of SQL you are using.